Update mysql 5.7 for 8.0 in phalcon 4.1 and php 7.4
i have a problem in update mysql version of my application, 8.0 version causes a 300% more loewst process in database compare of 5.7 version.
Any sugestions or cases for improve performance in this problem?
Need performance improve

How can we know if you don't show us what you are using ?  Note - you want to update this fast, as this is a too broad of question and people vote those down, we need a specific question like "this sql statement 'select * from table' is slow at 3.4 second,"  how can i improve?  Here is my table info (posts) .. we need data ..

@easleyfixed It's a general problem, the whole system is much slower

First place to start is the slowest query, lets see it.  Add EXPLAIN to the statement so it gives full info on performance.
